# Predefined arguments group for Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument

When we use the identical arguments in multiple functions, is there any clever way to write an efficient code?

`**kwargs` is ok, but I would like to use default values and typing.

For example,

```py
def f1(a: float=0.01, b: int=1, c: str="hello"):
    print("do something")

def f2(b: int=1, c: str="hello"):
    print("do something different")
```

In this code, I would like to something like this (I know this is invalid).

```py
bc = {b: int=1, c: str="hello"}

def f1(a: float=0.01, **bc):
    print("do something")

def f2(**bc):
    print("do something different")
```

(update)
I want to use the identical group of the arguments in different functions. For example, multiple machine learning algorithms (e.g. learning rate, epoch num, optimizer)

Answer (score 0):

If you use identical arguments in multiple functions, it may be time to refactor them into instance attributes of a class:

```
class f:
    def __init__(self, b: int=1, c: str="hello"):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def f1(self, a: float=0.01):
        print("do something")

    def f2(self):
        print("do something different")

obj = f(b=2, c="foo")
obj.f1(0.02)
obj.f2()
```

Comment: Sorry for my vague question, but I would like to use the same arguments in different functions.
As an example, I want to implement multiple machine learning algorithms as functions, and use the identical group of parameters (e.g. learning rate, epoch number, optimizer)